# GWT : SerializationException

Tags: spring, hibernate, gwt

I'm trying to use GWT + Spring + Hibernate
When lunshing the application I get this error:

com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = [com.asso.shared.model.Activite@64d6357a]

after using this method with the lists of the persistence classes:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> makeGWTSafe(List<T> list) {
        if(list instanceof ArrayList) {
            return (ArrayList<T>)list;
        } else {
            ArrayList<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>();
            newList.addAll(list);
            return newList;
        }
    }
```

with my lists I got this:

com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = [com.asso.shared.model.Personne@75a2fb58]

==========================================

I have searched in the other subjects but I can't find any solution!
How can I solve this serialization thing!?
I'm using List in my Persistence classes

Answer (score 2):

You need to send DTO object to client side (instead of original one backed by Hibernate). The problem is that your Personne object is actually a Hibernate proxy. Each time when you call some method on it Hibernate do some work (fetch collections from DB for example). There is no simple way to serialize such kind of objects.

Hibernate entities:

```
//Hibernate entity
public class Personne {

    private String name;
    private List<Address> addresses;
}

//Hibernate entity
public class Address {


}
```

Corresponding DTO objects:

```
public class PersonneDto {

    private String name;
    private List<AddressDto> addresses;
}

public class AddressDto {


}
```

Instead of sending Personne to client side you need to create new PersonneDto object, copy state to it and then send to UI. `Personne` cannot be used in client side because `Personne.getAddresses()` in most cases hit DB to fetch data (which is inpossible to do in client side JS). So each `Personne` must be replaced by `PersonneDto` on client side. As a downside you need to mantnain additional layaer of DTO objects and corresponding code to transform entities to DTOs. There are another approaches to this problem. See [this article](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate) for more details.

Comment: Please I need a very clear explanation and a runnable example if possible! If you can do that you should know that you saved me, a stranger somewhere on the globe

Comment: PS: the add(Personne p) worked, but when it comes to get() I have this serialization error

Comment: I didn't understand how and where to use the DTO class! In the server side I am Manipulating the Personne class, and I have ManyToMany relationships with other classes! How do I use the DTO here

Comment: There is detailed example in [this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate?hl=en) article. It is more clear for you?

Comment: So, approach with DTO was helpfull for you?